# Finding residue of quotient function

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

Find the residue of the complex function $z \mapsto \frac{e^z}{\cosh z}$ at $z=\frac{(2k+1)\pi i}{2}$

My attempt: Let $w=z-\frac{(2k+1)\pi i}{2}$.

$\begin{align}
\frac{e^z}{\cosh z} = \frac{e^z}{\frac{e^z + e^-z}{2}} = \frac{2}{1+e^{-2(w+\frac{(2k+1)\pi i}{2})}} =\frac{2}{1-e^{-2w}}
\end{align} = 2(1+e^{-2w}+e^{-4w}+...)$

I don't see any $c_{-1}$ coefficient coming from this.

Comment: $$\frac{1}{1-e^{-z}} = \frac{1}{1-(1-z+\mathcal{O}(z^2))} = \frac{1}{z(1+\mathcal{O}(z))}=\frac{1}{z}+\mathcal{O}(1)$$

Comment: thanks, I got it